# VSCode で haml ファイルを開いた時にハイライト表示されるようにしたい

Tags: vscode, haml

#### 実現したいこと

hamlのソースコードも見やすく色分けするようにしたい。

#### 状況

Rails 初学者のものですが、VSCodeにて `haml` に挑戦しようと `erb` → `haml` へ変換したところ、コードの色がモノクロとなってしまい、読みづらくなってしまいました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

erb や rb などのファイルは拡張機能のおかげで色がついていたのですが、haml へ変換したところモノクロになってしまったのですが、通常は色がつくのでしょうか。
（設定ミス？他の拡張機能とバッティングなどしている？など不明な状況）

調べ方が良くないのか、ググっても方法が見つかりませんでした。

ご存知の方いらっしゃいましたらご教示いただけると幸いです。
※slimも何かご存知でしたらご教示くださると嬉しいです。

Comment: [Search results - tag:haml | Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=tag%3Ahaml&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance) のどれかを入れて試してみるとか？

Comment: ＞cubick様
内容修正ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@kunif 様 ありがとうございます！！
拡張機能： [Better Haml](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=karunamurti.haml) を導入したところ解決しました！！
拡張機能の調べ方勉強になりました！